# How to get 2 and 3rd rank student from total Marks (Sum of Marks)

Tags: sql, sum, rank

I have `Students` table with columns `SID, NAME`, and a `Marks` table with columns `SID, SUBJECT, MARKS`.

How can I get 2nd and 3rd ranked students based on total marks?

I tried this SQL statement, but I get an error

```
SELECT
    s.[SID], S.Name,
    SUM(M.Marks) AS TotalMarks,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(marks)) AS Rank_ 
FROM
    Students S 
INNER JOIN
    Marks M ON S.[SID] = M.[SID]
GROUP BY
    S.Name, s.[SID] 
HAVING
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(marks)) IN (2, 3)
```

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the detail of the error message?